# How can I specify an 11ty collection in frontmatter?

Tags: nunjucks, eleventy

On my website, I want to show a list of collection items on pages corresponding to each collection. For example on the *Games* page, I want to show a list of all game related articles, on the *Politics* page, I want to show a list of all politics related articles, etc.

What I have right now is one Nunjucks template file for each such page, which I don't particularly like since they are the same except for the collection to show. Here is two of my templates, for my politics articles and for my games articles, where I extend a common boilerplate (*base.njk*) and in the main block, I first print some Markdown content and then comes the list of collection items:

```njk
{# politics.njk #}

{% extends "base.njk" %}

{% block main %}
<main>
    {{ content | safe }}
    <ul class="postlist no-bullets">
        {% for item in collections.politics %}
            {% include "partials/collection-list-item.njk" %}
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
</main>
{% endblock %}
```

```njk
{# games.njk #}

{% extends "base.njk" %}

{% block main %}
<main>
    {{ content | safe }}
    <ul class="postlist no-bullets">
        {% for item in collections.games %}
            {% include "partials/collection-list-item.njk" %}
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
</main>
{% endblock %}
```

As you can see, the only difference between these two files is `collections.politics` and `collections.games`. I would want to use one template, and in the frontmatter specify which collection I want. Since I'm already having one Markdown file per page the template used (for writing stuff before I begin listing articles), it would have been nice if it was possible. For example:

```md
<!-- politics.md -->
---
layout: articles-list.njk
title: Politics
listCollection: collections.politics
---
# Politics
Below is a list of all politics articles I've written.
```

```md
<!-- games.md -->
---
layout: articles-list.njk
title: Games
listCollection: collections.games
---
# Games
I think about games a lot. Below is a list of articles I've written on the topic.
```

```njk
{# articles-list.njk #}

{% extends "base.njk" %}

{% block main %}
<main>
    {{ content | safe }}
    <ul class="postlist no-bullets">
        {% for item in listCollection %}
            {% include "partials/collection-list-item.njk" %}
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
</main>
{% endblock %}
```

Is it possible to do what I want to do in some other way than to have multiple template files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be able to get to the collection using [computed data](https://www.11ty.dev/docs/data-computed/#using-javascript), though I'm not sure if you have access to the collections there.

A simpler approach: Set your frontmatter field to the name of the colletion you want to display as a string, then use that to get the collection in the template:

```yaml
<!-- politics.md -->
---
layout: articles-list.njk
title: Politics
listCollection: 'politics'
---
```

```
{# articles-list.njk #}

{% extends "base.njk" %}

{% block main %}
<main>
    {{ content | safe }}
    <ul class="postlist no-bullets">
        {% for item in collections[listCollection] %}
            {% include "partials/collection-list-item.njk" %}
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
</main>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Thanks! I will go to your second suggestion. I never thought about collections being associative arrays, for this is what `collections[listCollection]` is all about, isn't it?

Comment: @JohanNilsson Associative arrays don't exist in JS, there's just arrays (which are always numerically indexed) and objects. You can access object properties both using the dot-notation and the bracket notation, the latter being primarily useful for exactly this purpose, accessing a property where the property's name comes from a variable. Since collections in eleventy are objects, you can dynamically access one using a variable as the key. Nunjucks [imitates that behaviour](https://mozilla.github.io/nunjucks/templating.html#variables), so it works both in regular JS as well as in Nunjucks.

Comment: From the Nunjucks example, those are equivalent: `{{ foo.bar }}`, `{{ foo["bar"] }}`. The documentation doesn't mention it, but of course the `"bar"` string can also come from a variable. Here's a [resource on bracket notation in JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors#bracket_notation).

Answer (score 1):

The way I handled this on my blog (https://github.com/cfjedimaster/raymondcamden2020) was like so:

1. I create a collection of my categories. I do this by using .eleventy.js and eleventyConfig.addCollection. I use some JavaScript to get all of my posts, iterate over each ones list of categories, and creating a unique list. At the end, I've got a collection called categories.

```js
  eleventyConfig.addCollection("categories", collection => {
    let cats = new Set();
        let posts = collection.getFilteredByGlob("_posts/**/*.md");
        for(let i=0;i<posts.length;i++) {
      for(let x=0;x<posts[i].data.categories.length;x++) {
        cats.add(posts[i].data.categories[x].toLowerCase());
      }
        }

        return Array.from(cats).sort();
    });
```

2. I then made one page, categories.liquid, that is reponsible for generating my category pages. It's rather simple:

```html
---
pagination:
    data: collections.categories
    size: 1
    alias: cat
permalink: "categories/{{ cat | myEscape }}/"
layout: category
renderData:
    title: "{{ cat }}"
---
```

Notice I use `cat` for each item in the category and notice I've got *nothing* else in here. All the layout is done in the category layout page.

3. Here's the top portion of my category page:

```html
---
layout: default
---

{% assign posts = collections.posts | getByCategory: cat %}
```

So given I've got a collection of posts where each post has N categories assigned to it, I wrote a custom filter that just reduces this down to a post that has `cat` as one of it's categories.

S the end result is N category pages filled posts assigned to that category.

Comment: Thanks! I know about pagination, but I wanted to have some custom body text in my collection pages, and different text in each. I think I'm going with @MoritzLost's answer. I'll definitely check out your blog source code one day to pick up some tools of the trade. I'm rather new at Eleventy.